# How to create own async work in the promise body?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I write the function which emulated big work. I need to get the output:

```
Work started.
Hello!
Work done.
Bob
```

This is my "Hello World" example:

```js
function bigWork(user){
    console.log('Work started.');
    const p = new Promise(resolve => {

        setTimeout(() => {
            // here is some long calculatin must
            // be done async. Therefore I placed
            // it inside of setTimeout() function
            for(let n = 0; n < 100000; n++);

            console.log('Work done.');
            resolve(user);
        },0);
    });
    return p;
}

bigWork({name:'Bob', age:30}).then(user=> console.log(user.name));
console.log('Hello!');
```

Its output is the same like I expected. But I am forced to use `setTimeout()` function for it. I deliberately use `setTimeout()` function to get the console output that I need.

Can I get the same output without `setTimeout()` function using?

Comment: No, not if you're emulating the big work with a tight for-loop. That's going to block the thread and prevent _anything_ from happening until it's done running. And if your actual big work is also CPU-bound, you're going to have the same problem and promises are not the solution (at least not the whole solution). You need to look into options for running work on a separate thread. For example, by using [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers).

Comment: You're emulating async work, but you don't want to use async functions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use [`Promise.resolve`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve):

```js
function bigWork(user){
    console.log('Work started.');
    return Promise.resolve().then(() => {
        for(let n = 0; n < 100000; n++);
        console.log('Work done.');
        return user;
    });
}

bigWork({name:'Bob', age:30}).then(user=> console.log(user.name));
console.log('Hello!');
```

Be aware that although this ensures the order you wanted, it does not prevent the execution to be blocking *during* the execution of the `for` loop: it just happens in a particular order where the "work" is deferred until the current execution stack becomes empty.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to break it to you, but JavaScript is technically single threaded.

The reason it seems to work for you is because setTimeout code occurs only once the main "thread" is complete, so while your loop is blocking the javascript, your sample application doesn't really show that it is happening.

What you can do is use WebWorkers, which will achieve the multithreading you want, but is a whole beast in and of itself
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API

Comment: It is not really multithreading, as WebWorkers are isolated and can only communicate with the main process in a very restricted way. It is more like a isolated child process.

Comment: True, but the end result is that the code doesn't block, which is the implication of the question... I like the accepted answer for this one.  Can't wait for him to come back with a "new" question about why his code doesn't do what he wants lol

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you want something like below.

```js
  async function bigWork(user){
    console.log('Work started.');
    const p = await longCalculation(100, user);
   console.log('Work done.');
    return p;
}

function longCalculation(round, user){
     return new Promise((resolve) => {
      for(let n = 0; n < round; n++);
       resolve (user);
     })
}

bigWork({name:'Bob', age:30}).then(user=> console.log(user.name));
console.log('Hello!');
```

Comment: Hm... I see your code works in the  code snippet here, but it doesn't work in Node.js. I get error: `ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined`.

Comment: Create a test.js file and copy the above code to it. Then in your terminal write "node test.js" and it works on node too.